# how to make tidy-maven-plugin and spotless-maven-plugin to ignore comments formatting in pom.xml or do it in the same way?

Tags: maven, validation, pom.xml, spotless-maven-plugin

I am trying out maven plugins for maven `pom.xml` validation,
as our project pom.xml was in much neglected state, w/o formating etc.

I found that [spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-maven) can do with config later below by

`mvn spotless:apply`

and https://www.mojohaus.org/tidy-maven-plugin/

`mvn tidy:pom`.

The problem: while both are good and pointed to some problem,
and agree about meaningful pom.xml content,
they disagree about how to write comments (something, that I don't really want to make strict)

spotless wants multiline comment block to start like

```
<plugin>   
<!--
```

and
tidy wants in 1 line

```
<plugin><!--
```

Question: **how to make these plugins to ignore comments formatting
or do it in the same way?**

```xml
      <!-- mvn spotless:check by default is mapped to mvn verify (verify lifecycle phase)-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.30.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <java>
            <googleJavaFormat></googleJavaFormat>
          </java>
          <pom>
            <sortPom>
              <!-- see https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/blob/main/plugin-maven/README.md#sortpom -->
            </sortPom>
          </pom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spotless is using `sortpom-maven-plugin` to sort pom files. Sortpom parses the whole file as xml content and regenerates the file from that xml structure. Most information about line numbers and individual formatting is lost in this process, including formatted comments. I.e it treats the comments as any other xml content.
There are ways to ignore sections in the pom file with Sortpom, see [SORTPOM IGNORE](https://github.com/Ekryd/sortpom/wiki/IgnoringSections), but I don't know if it applicable to your use case.